# What does it mean 'exit 1' for a job status after rclone sync

Tags: exit-status, rclone

I am copying some large datasets to google drive using rclone in Linux on MobaXterm. First, I copy the dataset using;

```
-cpu:~$ nohup rclone copy /path_to_source/. /path_to_destination &
```

once copying is completed, I use sync to make sure everything is copied using;

```
-cpu:~$ nohup rclone sync /path_to_source/. /path_to_destination &
```

Now when check the job status using;

```
ps -ef | grep rclone
```

For one of the jobs, it gives;

```
[3]+  Exit 1         nohup rclone sync /path_to_source/. /path_to_destination &
```

I was expecting to see 'Done' instead of 'Exit 1'. What does this mean? Does it mean sync is unsuccessful? If so what would be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Exit 1` means your command resulted in exit code 1.

The exit code comes from either the `nohup` command, or the `rclone sync` command.
The former  will usually create exit codes with very high values on any errors, so it's probably from the latter.

If the `nohup` command worked, it will probably have created a `nohup.out` file in the directory you ran the command in. It contains any output the `rclone sync` command may have created, so if that file exists, reading it will probably solve the mystery.

[The documentation page of `rclone`](https://rclone.org/docs/) has a paragraph titled **List of exit codes** almost at the end of the page:

```
List of exit codes

0 - success
1 - Syntax or usage error
2 - Error not otherwise categorised
3 - Directory not found
4 - File not found
5 - Temporary error (one that more retries might fix) (Retry errors)
6 - Less serious errors (like 461 errors from dropbox) (NoRetry errors)
7 - Fatal error (one that more retries won’t fix, like account suspended) (Fatal errors)
8 - Transfer exceeded - limit set by --max-transfer reached
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer to which you linked *does* answer your question exactly.  `Exit 1` means that your backgrounded job completed, but threw a nonzero exit code (in this case, `1`) which usually indicates some sort of error condition.  You will see `Done` when the job's exit code is zero:

```
$ sleep 4 &
[1] 98565
$ # Wait a few seconds, and press Enter..
[1]+  Done                    sleep 4
$ ( sleep 4; exit 44 ) &
[1] 98613
$ # Wait a few seconds, and press Enter..
[1]+  Exit 44                 ( sleep 4; exit 44 )
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer was also helpful and I have voted for you.